# unpacked apk usign bundletool throws problem parsing package

Tags: react-native, expo, bundletool

I recently tried making an android app using react-native expo-cli and also generated the aab file then using bundle tool converted it into apks file which I renamed to .zip extracted and obtained the apk files, now when I try to install the app its gives problem parsing the package error

Answer (score 0):

You're not meant to install all the .apk files that are in the .apks file. Either use bundle tool `install-apks` command to install directly, or use the `extract-apks` to extract them but then make sure to install all of them in the same ADB session.